# Putting function in appropriate class

Tags: c#

```
public static FirstObjectType GetObject(SecondObjectType secondobjectType) 
{
         do something
}
```

Where should I put this function? Should I put it in SecondObjectType class or FirstObjectType class in terms of code readability, customs and traditions? Should the function be included in the return class or the parameter class from your experience?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: What's the point of GetObject()? Are you implementing a factory pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually put the method in the class that has the same type as the return type of the method.

eg:

```
public static FirstObjectType GetObject(SecondObjectType secondobjectType) 
{
         do something
}
```

would go in the FirstObjectType class.

Alternatively you can use the Factory Pattern and have a factory for getting the objects you need. Which could give you code simliar to the following:

```
FirstObjectTypeFactory.GetObject(SecondObjectType secondObjectType)
```

Then you always know which factory to get the object from based on its return type.

Comment: Agreed.  Usually when you want an object A, A is the first place you look.

Comment: I don't understand the point of having a static GetObject on FirstObjectType.  Why not just use a constructor?

Comment: If you use the constructor and a first object cannot be constructed / found from the second object then you cant return null if the object is not found - instead you just have an empty class. I prefer to return null if nothing should be returned rather than an instance of a class that is empty. its easier to check for, and if another developer is using the class they would have to know what to check for in the empty class to determine whether the request for the object was successful

Comment: I guess that depends on whether or not the caller expects the call to fail.  If failure is an option, then returning null is the way to go.  However, if failure is not an option, I would expect an Exception to be thrown.  Based on the question, there is no way to know this.

Comment: @Cadrell - I agree, There is no way of knowing if the method will fail, but as you say you should either throw and exception, or return null. Both suggestions would be better than having an initialised instance of the class.

Answer (score 1):

This is way to vague to answer, but I'll give a few general tips

If you have a collection of `FirstObjectTypes` and are trying to find the one that matches `SecondObjectType`, then it belongs to the class that owns the collection.  This could be a factory pattern.

If you are always creating a new `FirstObjectType`, it could just be a constructor for `FirstObjectType`.

Does `SecondObjectType` have to have knowledge of `FirstObjectType`?  If so, then it I would consider making it a method on `SecondObjectType`.

There are a million other scenarios and there is no one size fits all.

Answer (score 0):

I'll create an Extension Method for that.

Just add *this* in the signature

```
public static FirstObjectType GetObject(this SecondObjectType secondobjectType) 
{
    //do something
}
```

After that you can do:

```
SecondObjectType sobj = new SecondObjectType()
//code
FirstObjectType  fobj = sobj.GetObject();
```

And put it with my other extension method file like ExtensionMethods.cs.
Or if the class containing the GetObject method is static too, put it in the same class (In this case in the SecondObjectType's class)